# how to manage relationship (mysql) tables with java entity class, without a framework

Tags: java, mysql

i'm new in java and want to know if is possible manage relationships tables in java creating a class entity for every table i have created in mysql or only creating the fathers tables, but i don't know if necessary create a entity or just doit with a sql script consult in DAO class.

Workin a maven project with mysql and glassfish server.

Could you please guide me on this topic

[***this is my db diagram***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTNQO.png).

***this is my entity class:***

```java
  public class AdministratorUser {
    private int administratorUserId;
    private User user_userId;
    private Permission permission_permissionId;


    public AdministratorUser(int administratorUserId, User user_userId, Permission permission_permissionId) {
        this.administratorUserId = administratorUserId;
        this.user_userId = user_userId;
        this.permission_permissionId = permission_permissionId;
    }

    public int getAdministratorUserId() {
        return administratorUserId;
    }

    public void setAdministratorUserId(int administratorUserId) {
        this.administratorUserId = administratorUserId;
    }

    public User getUser_userId() {
        return user_userId;
    }

    public void setUser_userId(User user_userId) {
        this.user_userId = user_userId;
    }

    public Permission getPermission_permissionId() {
        return permission_permissionId;
    }

    public void setPermission_permissionId(Permission permission_permissionId) {
        this.permission_permissionId = permission_permissionId;
    }

}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Hey Roberto Vargas,

Welcome to the stack overflow developer community. If your new to java means please  learn jooq. it's an wonderful framework once your just configure in your project it will create an model (DAO)  class for your project. it's create model java class based on your table structure.

Please go through following link you will get a better clarity on this:

https://www.jooq.org/learn/

I hope it's helps you. Good Day..

Comment: Thanks a lot Sridhar! but i want to know if is necessary create the entity class with the relations table (like the example "AdministratorUser") or just create de fathers entity class (permissions, users, comments) and make the relations in query sql , in the DAO class, all this witout a framework, only java, im using the mvc pattern.

Comment: @RobertoVargas if possible can you explain why you don’t use framework in your project. Or can you explain more about your project that help me to understand and give the better answer to you. If don’t want frameworks you just use jdbc template to query the data from database. I need more clarity in your question.? I not able to understand your question properly

Comment: Yes of course, im creating a simple project to comment movies, i create a entity 'User' and i want to create userRegistred (this can create comments and add movies) and userAdmin (this can delete comments and users), this two have a FK 'users_usersId' and 'permissions_permissionId. Actually im ussing JDBC driver "com.myql.jdbc..." and create a project web with glassfish like local server. I think the inherence cut be a good way to manage them. I dont use a framework because i want to learn about pure java, and that way I will be able to use the framework more appropriately, i hope so